# PowerShell Remoting - Invoke-Command not Returning Output

Tags: powershell, remoting, invoke-command

I am running following command remotely from PowerShell in Admin mode. This gets the status of App Pool (in IIS) from remote machine.

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock {
    param($appPoolName) 
    Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $appPoolName
} -ArgumentList $appPoolName | select value
```

If I am passing correct values I am getting proper data in `$result` but if I am passing invalid server name, I am getting below error.

> "Connecting to remote server  failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request."

The issue is I am not getting anything in `$result` and even this is not going to Catch block. There is no way to identify if the command run successfully or not.

Please provide any pointers on how to get the command output in $result.

Note: I am the admin on remote machine and WinRM has been enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In order to catch the error, it needs to be terminating. You can force this with `-ErrorAction Stop`.

```
try {
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock {
        param($appPoolName) 
        Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $appPoolName
    } -ArgumentList $appPoolName -ErrorAction Stop | select value
}
catch {
    $result = [pscustomobject]@{"value"="Not Found"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Catch error with try/catch by adding `-ErrorAction Stop` and display last error with `$error[0]`

```
Try{
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
        param($appPoolName) 
        Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $appPoolName
    } -ArgumentList $appPoolName | Select-Object value
}
Catch{
    $result = $error[0]
}
```